# Running rufus scheduler on multiple nodes problem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rufus-scheduler

Running rufus-scheduler in a Rails 3 app without any problem.

But since my app is running in cluster of nodes, app1.myapp.com - app2.myapp.com, 
the rufus-scheduler is running the job app(N) times.

How can I make it run only on one server?

Comment: How are you causing the Rufus Scheduler process to be run? What code runs it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you thought of this naive solution:

```
# at initialization

if `hostname -f` == 'app1.myapp.com'
  $scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new
  $scheduler.every '5s' do
    puts "hello world"
  end
else
  # we're on another host, do not schedule anything
  $scheduler = nil
end
```

?

Comment: Good approach, but one might need to add redis-semaphore or similar to take over the scheduler on another host in case the primary fails. Also maybe `Socket.gethostname` is better than using an external command?

Comment: As written, my solution is naive. I am sure the OP refined it to suit his needs and his context.